# Using python-twitter behind a proxy

Tags: python, proxy, twitter, python-twitter

I have "created" a Twitter parser in Python 2.7, which pretty much can parse everything available from the API. As everyone else the REST API limit is killing me. I am trying to create a social graph (pretty big I'd say) and time is of the essence. So I thought, what if I could use a proxy? And the fact is I managed to with urllib, but any try to recreate the parser with urllib this would destroy all the hours put into python-twitter. So my Extended(question) is, can someone please explain how to patch the twitter.py with these instructions: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=205

Or even better, anyone knows any similar workarounds the REST API limit? Moreover, are any other python modules offering oAuth and proxy support?

Comment: Forgot to mention, found [link](https://github.com/dhananjaysathe/python-twitter-with-proxy) but also not working.

Comment: Just found out that you do not need to run twitter api from a proxy, in order to multiply your request limit. All you have to do is create applications(with the respective keys) from different twitter accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether python-twitter supports proxy. But, there is a project which implements proxy support for python-twitter. Have a look at https://github.com/dhananjaysathe/python-twitter-with-proxy